# Redefine command \subjclass[2010]{} to display only "Subject" instead of "Mathematics Subject Classification"?

Tags: amsart

In an amsart document, how can I redefine the command `\subjclass[2010]{}` to display only "Subject" instead of "2010 Mathematics Subject Classification"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change to made is a bit hidden. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{subjclassname@1991}{Subject}
\makeatother

\textheight=6cm \calclayout % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\title{A small paper}
\author{A. Uthor}

\begin{abstract}
Changing subject class name.
\end{abstract}

\subjclass{Primary 05C38, 15A15; Secondary 05A15, 15A18}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

A complete setup for all classification years; this way also `\subjclass[2010]{...}` will just print *Subject*.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{subjclassname@1991}{Subject}
\@namedef{subjclassname@2000}{Subject}
\@namedef{subjclassname@2010}{Subject}
\makeatother

\textheight=6cm \calclayout % just to make a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\title{A small paper}
\author{A. Uthor}

\begin{abstract}
Changing subject class name.
\end{abstract}

\subjclass[2010]{Primary 05C38, 15A15; Secondary 05A15, 15A18}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though there should be an easier way to be implemented straight from your article text, I found out a way by which you could change a few lines in the `amsart.cls` (which you could [download](https://www.ams.org/authors/packages/bull/amslatex/amsart.cls) and save *in the same folder* as your `.tex` file, using a different name like `amsartt.cls`).

Open `amsartt.cls` and edit the following lines:

```
\newcommand{\subjclassname}{%
    \textup{1991} Mathematics Subject Classification}
\@xp\let\csname subjclassname@1991\endcsname \subjclassname
\@namedef{subjclassname@2000}{%
    \textup{2000} Mathematics Subject Classification}
\@namedef{subjclassname@2010}{%
    \textup{2010} Mathematics Subject Classification}
```

as follows:

```
\newcommand{\subjclassname}{%
    \textup{} Subject}
\@xp\let\csname subjclassname@1991\endcsname \subjclassname
\@namedef{subjclassname@2000}{%
    \textup{} Subject}
\@namedef{subjclassname@2010}{%
    \textup{} Subject}
```

Now (repeat:) keeping this new file in the same directory as your tex file, which could look like:

```
\documentclass{amsartt}

\begin{document}
    \title{A small paper}
    \begin{abstract}
     Changing subject class name.
    \end{abstract}
    \subjclass{Primary 05C38, 15A15; Secondary 05A15, 15A18}

    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

you get an **output** which should serve your purpose:

[image]